# FX options for retail trader

Tags: options, trading, foreign-exchange, foreign-currency, ofx

I would like to trade options on the FX market, say EURUSD and GBPUSD. I have seen that there are options on the CME that have FX futures as underlying and also some options on spot on the Philadelphia exchange. But bid ask spreads are pretty wide in both cases. Is there any better alternative market if I want to trade FX options with enough liquidity and hence tighter spreads?

Comment: Frankly, retail traders probably shouldn't get involved in fx at all. The risk is quite high, and it is ultimately a zero-sum game [as opposed to economy-wide growth experienced in long-term investing].

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link that shows currency option activity during regular market hours:

https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/euro-fx_quotes_globex_options.html#optionProductId=8117&strikeRange=ATM

An option has an expensive premium to pay but limits the amount of loss that is possible.

I would instead take futures currency positions or over-the-counter forex positions and just have a stop-loss order. The weekend downside closed-market possibility could be avoided.

For instance, close the position at the end of each trading week and re-open it at the begin of each trading week. During the trading week the stop-loss order is no protection for only about one hour per-day on the forex market or only about 45 minutes per-day on the futures market. Actually some of the forex market does stay open from 5 PM to 6 PM but it is not very liquid.

Now a stop-loss order is not good protection when and if the market goes historically ill-liquid. The market can drastically move past the stop-loss before executing the order.

Comment: This is not great advice. Whether a stop loss order would actually trigger in time to prevent catastrophic loss even during liquid hours depends entirely on the leverage used [extreme leverage being quite common amongst some forex traders, particularly novice ones who underestimate the risk]. In particular, central bank decisions can instantly change the value of their home currency by 1%+; no amount of liquidity is enough to catch a stoploss order during a live feed of the Fed saying "Due to unforeseen economic slowdown, the projected path of the federal funds rate has been revised downward."

Comment: It might not matter if the stop-loss doesn't trip because the spike might not hold. A black-swan event is where the spike continues on. Investors don't need to be protected from all possible losses but they do want to avoid the black-swan events. Well, one example, in January of 2015, the Swiss franc spiked and the currency market went illiquid.

Comment: What I'm saying is that this advice sounds naively optimistic - forex contains real risk, particularly due to the magnitude of leverage often associated with it. Price changes based on government policy shifts during trading hours frequently happen, and instantly change the value of a currency. Saying that the Fed announcing an interest rate change might cause a temporary 'spike' in price is completely off-base. If you had 50x leverage (which some people get into with Forex), then a 1% value change would wipe out half your portfolio instantly, stop-loss or not.

Comment: Well, I've had forex profits when a spike reverses with the Fed speech. Spikes in general often don't hold as they are often initial over-reactions. But certainly, consider options instead of futures and just pay the premium to lock-in the maximum amount of possible loss.

Comment: Oh, the brokers that specialize in trading, they recommend "stop-limit" orders instead of "stop" orders. So there may be a statistical faith in a spike reversal or there just may be a fear of orders executed during illiquid moments. Well, the branch subject relates to a spike so severe that a stop-limit order is jumped-over.